# how to install the iso file of ubuntu 14.04 into VirtualBox in means of command line, which is installed in the linux server from windows using putty

Tags: server, virtualbox, ssh, system-installation, remote-access

This situation is somewhat complicated!

I use win7 os and I have to work on the Linux server by the SSH client, PuTTY.

Right now I have installed the VirtualBox into the Linux server in means of command line(since I have to install the VB by PuTTY, where there is no GUI). Then I have to install the iso file of ubuntu-14.04 into the VB in means of command line, too. In order to complete it, I downloaded the VirtualBox_usermanual and executed the procedures as the manual says. However, when I enter the command as follows, the green focus just stayed there

---

---

[b50039@neptune ubuntu]$ vboxheadless --startvm ubuntu_14_04

Oracle VM VirtualBox Headless Interface 4.3.10

(C) 2008-2014 Oracle Corporation

All rights reserved.

VRDE server is listening on port 5000.

[green focus]

---

---

Could anybody help me? Emergency！！！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a link to a tutorial

http://www.howopensource.com/2011/06/how-to-use-virtualbox-in-terminal-commandline/

This is a list of Virtual Box commands

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#idp55479184

Comment: Thx a lot. But the above is not my need. I have downloaded the user manual as u gave me. But the manual do not work at all...

Comment: I mainly read the Chapter 7, which contains the information of remote virual machines, and Chapter 8. When I execute the last step as the Chapter 7 describes, which is " vboxheadless --startvm ubuntu_14_04", "ubuntu_14_04" is the name of my VM. Then, I don't know what to do next...

Comment: [link] (http://www.howopensource.com/2011/06/how-to-use-virtualbox-in-terminal-commandline/) this is the tutorial that is step by step, you just have to plug in your info. The other link is just a list of commands that you may need, and it explains them briefly.

Comment: the command you gave me is the Step 3, I have allocated the hd, rm,cpu,etc.. how to add image to the comment? I want to show you the detailed steps.

Answer (score 3):

#### Create a VM from command line

We can fully create and control Virtual Box from the command line using [VBoxManage](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html). This involves all of the follwing steps nicely outlined in the [Virtual Box Manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html#idp56277008):

- Create and register a virtual machine making sure the `ostype` is correct.
- Make appropriate machine settings (RAM, VRAM, CPU, network, etc.)
- Create a virtual hard drive VDI for this machine
- Add an IDE controller for this drive
- Add the virtual hard disk VDI to this IDE controller
- Attach the boot .iso file to the VM
- run the VM to install from the CD .iso file
- optionally install the guest additions for shared folders support

You may want to use an RDP viewer to be able to view the machine's outputs.

#### Export and import an existing VM

We can see that the above involves quite a lot of single steps to define and set up our virtual machines. In case we are not so familiar with Virtual Box it may be much easier to create, set up, and test a virtual machine on a computer with a graphical interface, export the running and tested VM to then just import the virtual machine on our remote computer:

- [Importing and exporting virtual machines](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#ovf)
- [Importing a virtual machine using VBoxManage](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-import)

Comment: The last result is as below.<br/>[b50039@neptune ~]$ vboxheadless --startvm ubuntu_14_04
Oracle VM VirtualBox Headless Interface 4.3.10
(C) 2008-2014 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.

VRDE server is listening on port 5000.
<br/>I want to know what to do next.

Comment: that one seems easier .. just exporting

Comment: how to export? you means that I export the iso file of ubuntu?

Comment: @tank had you installed the Oracle "Extension Pack" (needed for RDP)?

Comment: @Takkat exactly! I have done. without the extention package, the VRDP can not work.When I start up my VM, there is a prompt,"VRDE server is listening on port 5000.", which means that I am communicating with the server. The confusion I meet is that how I do continue installing the iso file I have set up in command line completely.

Comment: @tank your RDP client should now listen to port 5000 to view the machine's output.

Comment: @Takkat that's ture! But, what can I do next?? There just leaves me a green shining focus. I cannot input any commands. The ultimate goal for me is to install the iso file of ubuntu. Could u help me how to install the iso into my server??