# Can I create a virtual machine through ssh

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, ssh

I am trying to configure VirtualBox on Ubuntu Server 14.04. But when I try to start a VM I get an error message saying:

> VT-x is disabled in the BIOS.

Searching for this error message lead me to multiple pages suggesting to reboot the machine and change the settings in the BIOS. Unfortunately at the moment I only have ssh access to this server. Through ssh I can reboot the machine, but I don't know how to change the BIOS settings.

Is there any other way to get a virtual machine running on this server which I can only access through ssh? I tried disabling VT-x in VirtualBox but am told that is not a valid configuration when using a 64-bit guest.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to run a 64-bit guest we need both, a VT-x/AMD-V enabled CPU on the host, and enable the VT-x features of the guest.

#### Host BIOS

In case of a remote server we may not be able to change BIOS settings of the server to enable virtualization. See the following question on how to find out if the server is capable of hardware virtualization:

- [How to determine if CPU VT extensions are enabled in bios?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103965/how-to-determine-if-cpu-vt-extensions-are-enabled-in-bios)

#### Virtualbox settings

Enabling VT-x for an existing virtual machine can be done from the command line with

```
VBoxManage modifyvm <uuid|vmname> --hwvirtex on
```

#### Create a new VM

If we can't enable VT-x we can only create a 32-bit virtual machine. This can be done remotely through an SSH session, but it may be a much easier approach to create the VM locally to then export it to the server's instance of VirtualBox:

- [how to install the iso file of ubuntu 14.04 into VirtualBox in means of command line, which is installed in the linux server from windows using putty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454202/how-to-install-the-iso-file-of-ubuntu-14-04-into-virtualbox-in-means-of-command)

Answer (score 0):

If your server has X11, you can ssh with X forwarding and run the virtualbox GUI:

```
ssh user@host -X
virtualbox
```

Comment: Tried that already got an error message saying: `VT-x is disabled in the BIOS.`